# Defining td width using a div inside the td VS defining width on the td itself?

Tags: html, css

When I want to set the width of a td, I style the td with a width like:

```
<td style="width:125px">...</td>
```

I have seen td width set by adding an empty div like this:

```
<td>
  some text
  <div class="h-spacer" style="width: 125px"></div>
</td>
```

.h-spacer {
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

What's the advantage with this method? It looks to me just extra unnecessary markup.

**Addition:**

This question is **NOT** about tables vs div's. It's very specific. It's about the different ways in setting a td width. I believe the author of the second example knows his css. I want to know why he used the more complicated way and if it's handy for something I am not aware of.

Comment: Is this for a table heading by chance?

Comment: could you accomplish the task using only divs?

Comment: There are very **very** ***very*** little cases, where a div inside of a TD should ever be used, I hope you have a very good reason why you have a div inside of a td.

Comment: It needs to be a table. It's displaying tabular data. Same used for form layout.

Comment: @mudfalcon no. The td's are in a form.

Comment: @BrettAdamsGA My reply is in the addition.

Comment: @Truth It's not helpful when you say something shouldn't be done in some way when you don't explain why not. Plus I said "I have seen..". That should have clued you that it's not my code.

Answer (score 0):

IMO they are both bad.  The first includes inline styling when they should be using either a style block in the head or a css file.   The second puts a div inside a TD which is not a good practice either, with or without the inline styling.

the question would be whether you can accomplish what you need (relatively easily) with div's vs using a table.  If so then use the divs if not then use a table but don't nest divs in a table.

As prefaced, this is my opinion only :-)

Comment: You didn't answer my specific question. First.. using inline css or not is a different issue. I used inline to simplify my example. Using a div inside a td is OK.
Second.. using a table vs a div for layout is also a different issue. I am sure the author knows a td can have its own width & it's simpler. The question is whether using a div like that is buying him something.

Comment: No it isn't buying him anything and it is a bad practice especially with the way he is using it here.

Answer (score 0):

After clearing your question I understood what you were asking.

So yes, it's considered bad practice to have unnecessary markup, and it adds no value whatsoever.

It's most likely a CMS which uses it to generalize the final result, however it shouldn't be done. Stick with setting the width normally via CSS.